# Internet Explorer not properly downloading image from WCF

Tags: c#, html, image, wcf, internet-explorer

I have a WCF service which provides an endpoint to dynamically generate a QR-Code image. The image is first written to a memory stream `tempStream`. I then have the following code in the endpoint:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Clear();
response.ClearContent();
response.ClearHeaders();

response.Buffer = false;
response.ContentType = "image/png";
response.CacheControl = "No-Cache";

response.AddHeader("Content-Length", tempStream.Length.ToString())
response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

tempStream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);

response.Flush();
response.End();
```

It works fine in Firefox. The image is downloaded if I hit the endpoint manually and it loads inline if I reference the endpoint as the `src` attribute in an `img` tag. However, in IE, the image does not load inline in an `img` tag, and if I try to hit the endpoint manually, it loads the full image the first time but any subsequent refreshes (seemingly until the browser is restarted), it only loads part of the image.

Upon inspection of the network tab in the F12 window, it seems to be downloading exactly 1.00 KB of data (including headers) from the server, meaning it gets about 750 KB of image data. Then it makes another identical request to the server and gets only the headers back with no image data. The `Content-Length` header is set correctly to the size of the image; IE just doesn't download that much. Again, Firefox is fine.

My coworker recommended that I set `transferMode` to `Streamed` in `Web.config`, which I did, but that didn't work either. How can I get IE to download the entire image in one go?

**EDIT:**

I should note that when running the WCF service in Visual Studio's IIS Express server, Internet Explorer works fine. It is only when the application is deployed to IIS 7.5 that the problem occurs. Firefox works fine in both environments.

**EDIT 2:**

I just added `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to the response, right before `response.End()`, and it fixed the issue. IE now downloads the entire response and does not attempt to make a second request. Why?! `response.Flush();` should block the request and emit **all** data to the client before `response.End()` is called, and as far as I know, `response.End()` also flushes the stream so calling `Flush()` manually is redundant. Why does blocking the thread explicitly for one second make it work? I should also note that if I don't put `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in, it still works for the **first request** because .NET has to JIT-compile the backend each time the AppPool is restarted, which blocks the request for a certain amount of time, just as `Thread.Sleep(1000)` does.

Comment: Can you provide the response headers that you see in the F12 window for the first and second request, and the request headers for the second request. Also, is it doing a HEAD or GET on the second request? Btw, WCF doesn't support Accept-Ranges.

Comment: I can post them tomorrow, but there's nothing out of the ordinary on them. I was using Accept-Ranges as an experiment because it seemed like IE was only downloading part of the data WCF returned and I wasn't sure if changing the Accept-Ranges values would make it want to download the whole response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually solved it now. Instead of using HttpContext.Current.Response, I'm now using WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse. Also, instead of writing to the response's output stream, I'm returning a Stream object from the endpoint, specifically the MemoryStream I'm saving the image to (after it has been seeked back to 0). There does not seem to be a consistent way to have write operations to an `HttpResponse` block until the transfer is finished, so the request always ends too soon. Even Firefox was having issues with larger images. Returning a `Stream` object from the endpoint function apparently makes WCF wait until all the data is sent before ending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
```

Comment: Would fileName just be the name of the endpoint with the png extension? There's no actual file involved here, but the endpoint appears to clients as an image/png file.

Comment: Okay, I tried adding that header and it did not work. It still only downloads 1.00KB of the request and then makes another one, which only returns the headers. I know the server is sending all the data for every response (I am outputting the response to a file as well as the response stream so I can be sure), but IE doesn't think it is.